# trying to run a project from github but unable to do it in andoird studio flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, github, rubiks-cube

Some of the things I find very pretty confusing as a beginner in flutter.As described in github about using the usage but don't know anything about it.I don't find main file in the source code and also showing so much error in code which I don't know how to resolve it.Overall don't have any idea how to run this project.
So the project that I want to run it from flutter android studio is below.
[Github Link:](https://github.com/tiagohm/cuber)

I want to run this project from github in andoid studio flutter but unable to do it that's why I want to know the whole process

Comment: Run -> Edit configurations -> Dart entrypoint -> Here select the file in which is the main method.

Comment: After that, one by one check and fix all errors (By the way, your project seems to be a package not an UI app)

Answer (score 0):

1. **Copy the main.dart file into the lib folder:**

   - Navigate to the 'lib' folder in your project.
   - Paste the main.dart file into this folder.
2. **Set Dart path in Android Studio:**

   - Open Android Studio.
   - Go to 'File' > 'Settings' > 'Languages & Frameworks' > 'Dart'.
   - Set the Dart SDK path to the appropriate location.
3. **Run the Code:**

   - Open the main.dart file in Android Studio.
   - Right-click on the file and select 'Run'.
4. **Code Execution in Console:**

   - After running the code, check the console in Android Studio for any output or errors.
5. **Check Screenshots:**

   - Capture screenshots of the running application for reference or documentation.

Ensure each step is followed accurately to execute the code successfully. If you encounter any issues, refer to the console output for debugging.

[image]

[Android studio project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXUjE.png)

[image]